# Display elements in an arraylist in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jtextarea

I'm creating a word game in which the player must make as many words as possible using the letters in the word given. (Example: The word given is "elephant" so possible answers would be pant and help). I want to display the right answers into a textbox. Right now, the only thing that displays are the blank text areas.

Here is the code that puts the words into their respective arraylists:

```
public void checkAnswers() { 
    ArrayList<String> validAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> wrongAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> notFound = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> compare = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (r == 0){
    compare = arr1Sub;
    }
    else if (r == 1){
            compare = arr2Sub;
    }
    else if(r == 2){
            compare = arr3Sub;
    }
    else{
            compare.add("error");
            System.out.println(compare);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++){
        if (compare.contains(inputList.get(i))){ 
                validAnswers.add(inputList.get(i));
        }
        else if (!compare.contains(inputList.get(i))){
                wrongAnswers.add(inputList.get(i));
        }
        else{
                notFound.add(compare.get(i)); 
        }

    for(String s : validAnswers){
        txtvalidWords.append(s.toString()); 
    }
```

Here is the code for the GUI:

```
public void CheckAnswersGUI(){
    JPanel answersPanel = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel wrongPanel = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel possiblePanel = new JPanel(); 
    container = new JPanel(); 

    lblvalid = new JLabel("Valid Answers"); 
    txtvalidWords = new JTextArea("",30,30); 
    lblwrong = new JLabel("Wrong Answers"); 
    txtwrongWords = new JTextArea("",30,30); 
    lblpossible = new JLabel("Answers Not Found"); 
    txtpossibleWords = new JTextArea("",30,30); 

    btnPlayAgain = new JButton("Play Again"); 
    btnPlayAgain.addActionListener(this);  

    FlowLayout checkLayout = new FlowLayout(); 
    answersPanel.setLayout(checkLayout); 
    wrongPanel.setLayout(checkLayout); 
    possiblePanel.setLayout(checkLayout);

    container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container,BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); 
    container.add(answersPanel); 
    container.add(wrongPanel); 
    container.add(possiblePanel);  
    container.add(btnPlayAgain);   

    inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String text = inputWords.getText(); 
    String[] words = text.split("\\s"); 

    for (String word : words){
        inputList.add(word); 
    }

    answersPanel.add(lblvalid);  
    answersPanel.add(txtvalidWords); 
    wrongPanel.add(lblwrong); 
    wrongPanel.add(txtwrongWords); 
    possiblePanel.add(lblpossible); 
    possiblePanel.add(txtpossibleWords); 
    getContentPane().add(container); 

    setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo (null);
    setSize (700,500);
    setTitle ("Check Your Answers");
    setVisible(true);
}   

    }
```

Comment: Where do you call the `checkAnswers`?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that I think you are trying to get the input from the text area when there is no text.  You have this in your constructor

```
String text = inputWords.getText();
```

There is no initial text, so That will do nothing.

I'm assuming in your `actionPerformed`, is where you call the `checkAnswers`, so I'll offer this suggestion. Take that code from your constructor and put it into your `actionPerformed()`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String text = inputWords.getText(); 
    String[] words = text.split("\\s"); 

    for (String word : words){
         inputList.add(word);
    }

    // then call the check answers. 
    checkAnswers();
}
```

What happens when you have it in the constructor is when the program first starts, it will try and read an empty text area. Now when you have it in the actionPerformed, it won't try to read it until the button is pressed.

**Edit:** answers are coming from a different class (as stated in OP comment)

Lets say you have this class `Answers`

```
public class Answers {
    private ArrayList<String> answers;

    public ArrayList<String> getAnswers(){
        return answers;
    }
}
```

In your `checkAnswers()`, you should create an instance of that class inside the method so that you can reference those answer.

```
public void checkAnswer(){
    Answers ans = new Answers();

    ArrayList<String> answers = ans.getAnswer();
}
```

Now you can use those answers from your other class to compare.

**Edit 2:**

```
public class PlayGame {
    private ArrayList<String> validAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> wrongAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> notFound = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getValidAnswers(){
        return validAnswers;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWrongAnswers(){
        return wringAnswers;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNotFound(){
        return notFound;
    }

    public void checkAnswers(String text) {
        // get text from texArea and use that text 
        // I'm guess to populate your compare list
    }
}

public class GUI extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea inputTextArea = new JTextArea();
    JButton checkAnswers = new JButton("Check Answers");

    PlayGame game = new PlayGame();

    public GUI {
        ...

       checkAnswers.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               String text = inputTextArea.getText();

               game.checkAnswers(text);

               ArrayList<String> validAnswers = game.getValidAnswers();
               ArrayList<String> wrongAnswers = game.getWrongAnswers();
               ArrayList<String> notFound = game.getNotFound();

               // code to append these lists to their corresponding text areas
           }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I still can't get the text to display. Right now, I have the answers in one class and then GUI's in another. I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how to compare the inputList with the answers arrayList in the other class and then display ONLY the correct answers.

Comment: I think in your `checkAnswer()` you should create an instance of your class that has the answers. Then reference those list in inside the method

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Maybe you want to do something like that.

Comment: Thanks! I think this should work. I have 3 JTextArea's that need to display different arraylists. I'm thinking of using conditional statements within the getAnswer method for instance, if JTextArea 1, then display ArrayList 1. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose and necessity of the conditional. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sure. So there are 3 JTextAreas - one for the valid answers, one for the wrong answers (if any), and one for all other possible answers. The current logic that runs through the lists to compare answers and place words in the appropriate list is in one class while the actionListener is in the GUI class. I want to use conditionals so that the appropriate lists get put in the right textarea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43285/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-user2898681)